Hibernate 6. OneToOne EAGER relationship and N+1 problem
I have simple example with oneToOne relationship.
Database scheme
create table if not exists Room
(
    id   int primary key generated always as identity,
    name text not null
);
create table if not exists RoomInfo
(
    id        int primary key generated always as identity,
    room_id   int references Room (id),
    info_name text
);

Hibernate scheme

@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
class Room(
    @Column(name = "name")
    val name: String,
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    val id: Int = 0

    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true, mappedBy = "room")
    var roomInfo: RoomInfo? = null
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "roominfo")
class RoomInfo(
    @Column(name = "info_name")
    val infoName: String,
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    val room: Room
) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    val id: Int = 0
}

When I try to find room by id (simple method findById from JpaRepository) I see good left join request
Hibernate: select r1_0.id,r1_0.name,ri1_0.id,ri1_0.info_name from room r1_0 left join roominfo ri1_0 on r1_0.id=ri1_0.room_id where r1_0.id=?

But when I try to use JpaRepository findAll() I take N+1 problem
Hibernate: select r1_0.id,r1_0.name from room r1_0
Hibernate: select ri1_0.id,ri1_0.info_name,r1_0.id,r1_0.name from roominfo ri1_0 left join room r1_0 on r1_0.id=ri1_0.room_id where ri1_0.room_id=?
Hibernate: select ri1_0.id,ri1_0.info_name,r1_0.id,r1_0.name from roominfo ri1_0 left join room r1_0 on r1_0.id=ri1_0.room_id where ri1_0.room_id=?

Try to add @Fetch(JOIN) but it is not fixed.
How can I say Hibernate use oneToOne as left join in any operations?
